# How to control spacing between underline and subtitles when burning them using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

## Table of contents

- The context
- Minimal working example: underline subtitles in VTT files
- Minimal working example: underline subtitles in ASS files
- Attempt on making adding styles in a VTT file

## The context

I'm using `ffmpeg` for burning subtitles into a video. Some of the lines in the subtitles are underlined, and I want to be able to change the spacing between the line that underlines the subtitle and the content of the subtitle.

I know how to underline subttiles in VTT and ASS subtitles (see minimal working examples below). I found documentation on these two file formats ([see relevant section in the VTT specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/webvtt1/), [documentation on ASS tags in Aegis official website](https://aegisub.org/docs/latest/ass_tags/)), but none of them mentioned separation between the underline and the content of the subtitles.

It is worth mentioning that CSS rules can be specified in VTT files ([see official documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/webvtt1/#styling)). Thanks to this, it would be possible to use the CSS property [text-underline-offset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-underline-offset) to control the spacing. However, It seems that ffmpeg can't interpret them, see section below "Attempt on adding styles to a VTT file and burn the subtitles".

My question is: Is it possible to define the separation between the underline and the subtitles in a ASS file or a VTT file? If not, what alternatives do I have to accomplish the same result using ffmpeg?

## Minimal working example: underline subtitles in VTT files

```
WEBVTT

00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:01.000
A subtitle in a VTT file with <u>underline</u>

00:00:01.000 --> 00:00:02.000
A subtitle in a VTT file without underline
```

```sh
ffmpeg -v error -y \ 
       -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=300x300 -t 2 \
       -vf "subtitles=my-subtitles.vtt" \
       output.avi
```

[image]

## Minimal working example: underline subtitles in ASS files

```
[Script Info]
ScriptType: v4.00+

[Events]
Format: Start, End, Text
Dialogue: 00:00:00.00, 00:00:01.00, A subtitle in a ASS file with {\u1}underline{\u0}
Dialogue: 00:00:01.00, 00:00:02.00, A subtitle in a ASS file without underline
```

```sh
ffmpeg -v error -y \
       -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=300x300 -t 2 \
       -vf "subtitles=my-subtitles.ass" \
       output.avi
```

[image]

## Attempt on adding styles to a VTT file and burn the subtitles

I found [this](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/8684) thread in the ffmpeg official website on ffmpeg not being able to read STYLE tags. The user reported that the style defined in the VTT file wasn't being read. I tried it in my computer, but it still didn't work, so it seems that ffmpeg can't parse lines that define CSS styles (the ffmpeg version that I'm using is v6.0).

```
WEBVTT

::cue(.white){ color: white; }

1
00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:01.000 line:77% position:50% align:middle
<c.white>Hello World</c>
```

```sh
ffmpeg -v error -y \
       -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=300x300 -t 2 \
       -vf "subtitles=my-subtitles.vtt" \
       output.avi
```